# How to open project to edit using Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I just started using the new free Team Foundation Server (http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) I have a project which is checked in and I can see all the source in the source viewer on the website.

I am connected to my project within Visual Studio.  But, there is absolutely nothing appearing in my solution explorer and I don't seem to be able to figure out how to load all of the source so that I can work on my project.

Any suggestions?  I have no idea how to use this and I have read all the tutorials on the website, but they don't show me how to actually open my project.

Again, I am connected to the project but nothing is showing up in "Solution Explorer".

Comment: Have you mapped the source to a local folder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Team Explorer navigate to your project and double click on the solution.

Or, go to File... Source Control... Advanced... Open from Source Control.

You need to have your Workspace mapped for any option to work.

To map the workspace, select the workspaces option from the Workspace drill down in the Source Control Explorer. From there select your workspace you want to map and edit it. All you simply have to do from there is select the local folder.

Comment: Thank you!  I don't know why this was not included in the documentation on tfs.visualstudio.com.

Comment: @shashwat I've edited my answer to include those instructions.